# How can i integrate Hero framework?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to use [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero) framework. I don't get any pod command from their documentation. I have used pod "Hero". It's worked but after installing and downloading pod when try to open project it says

> Xcode 9 does not support building or migrating Swift 2.x targets"

[image: Error message]

How can i solve this?

Comment: Can you show your podfile? What version of Hero was installed? Also, giving your project the name "Hero" may be causing some confusion, because it isn't clear if the message refers to your main target or the pod target.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the pod installation section in their documentation [here](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero/blob/master/docs/Installation.md).

If the process not work you try to read more...

This error means that XCode 9 does not offer any solution to migrate from Swift 2 to 4.

In fact into `Build Setting` you can switch from Swift 3.2 or 4.

You can try to open the project with XCode 8 firstly (that support Swift 2) and then after converting the library to Swift 3, reopen the project with XCode 9.